# CA2000 Dispose warning when reference held in a ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, concurrentdictionary

I have a parent class that has a collection of child classes. Both classes are `IDisposable`. I am receiving warning **CA2000** ("Call Dispose on object ... before all references to it are out of scope."), but I don't want to `Dispose()` it in the same method call it's created, as the child has a long lifetime. I'm keeping a reference to it in the parent class. If that reference is in a `Dictionary` or a `ConcurrentBag`, all is well. If the reference is in a `ConcurrentDictionary`, **CA2000** is listed.

As far as I can tell I'm implementing `IDisposable` correctly. Perhaps the way I'm iterating a concurrent collection and calling `Dispose()` could be improved, although I suspect that's not the source of the warning.

Is this a bug in the compiler/warnings, or can I achieve compliance through code? My stab at a theory is that it's being of the function syntax used to add the reference, but I'm not sure.

The following example reproduces the warning, with `child1` and `child3` being fine, but `child2` producing the warning, when the only difference is the container type:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

public class ParentDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ChildDisposable> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, ChildDisposable>();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChildDisposable> concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChildDisposable>();
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<ChildDisposable> concurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<ChildDisposable>();

    public void CreateChild()
    {
        // I want to create these disposable children, use them beyond the lifetime of this method call, and dispose of them when this parent class is disposed of
        var child1 = new ChildDisposable(); // No warning
        var child2 = new ChildDisposable(); // Warning CA2000  Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object created by 'new ChildDisposable()' before all references to it are out of scope.
        var child3 = new ChildDisposable(); // No Warning
        this.dictionary.Add("key", child1);
        this.concurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate("key", child2, (k, v) => child2);
        this.concurrentBag.Add(child3);
    }

    #region IDisposable Pattern
    private bool disposedValue = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                foreach (var key in this.dictionary.Keys)
                {
                    this.dictionary[key].Dispose();
                }

                foreach (var key in this.concurrentDictionary.Keys)
                {
                    this.concurrentDictionary[key].Dispose();
                }

                foreach (var child in this.concurrentBag)
                {
                    child.Dispose();
                }
            }

            this.disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion IDisposable Pattern
}

public class ChildDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private EventWaitHandle waitObject = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

    #region IDisposable Pattern
    private bool disposedValue = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposedValue)
        {
            this.waitObject.Dispose();
            this.disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion IDisposable Pattern
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem in your code, it's an oversight in the version of FxCop you are using.

This has been fixed in the latest version. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3082